# How to calculate sin using System.Data.Compute() in C#

Tags: c#

I'm new here! I'm a newbie in C#. One of my friends challenged me to create scientific calculator. I searched and found an easy way to make it here - using the System.Data library. For an example we have this:

```
string math = "5 + 3 * 3";
string answer = new DataTable().Compute(math, null).ToString();
```

This worked pretty easy with basic expressions, but I can't seem to find a way how to make the calculator be able to calculate sin, cos e.t.c. Anybody has an idea?

PS: I'm not good in english so plz forgive me

Comment: `DataTable` and its methods are intended for operating on rows and columns, not for scientific calculations. Available options are [documented here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) and are limited to sql like expressions.

Comment: I'm aware of that. I just wanted to ask if it's possible, because I've already built the calculator around that way.

Comment: I don't think its possible, may be you can take a look at [specialized libraries](http://mathparser.org) for this purpose.

Comment: Does this library that you linked works for C#, because I don't see it on the page? EDIT: I saw that it says .NET, so yes

Comment: Let it be a lesson for your future programming career: don't abuse things for purposes they are not designed for. The name `System.Data` already gives it away, it's not meant to do math. Things like that may come back to bite you in the butt later. Writing a calculator is pretty complicated, unless you want to write your own parser, but if you want to use a default solution anyway, use one that is meant for doing math, not manipulating data.

Comment: I was just experimenting with it dude. I saw that method as an answer in this website, this is why I tried to create calculator based on it, I wasn't aware what was the purpose of it, just used it in my code, because it was usable, didn't know its actual purpose. I will look into things before I use them, thanks for all the replies tho!

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to Mat J for telling me about mXparser! I found a way of calculating through it without changing alot of code!

Here is the mXparser: http://mathparser.org/

This is how the code has changed:
It was:

```
string math = "5 + 3 * 3";
string answer = new DataTable().Compute(math, null).ToString();
```

Now it is:

```
string math = "5 + 3 * 3";
Expression e = new Expression(math);
math = e.calculate();
```

The only thing is that it works with Expressions instead of strings, but it still works really easy and simple!

I want to thanks for the fast answers of everybody! You really helped me out!

Comment: Glad to know, Conside including the link and an example code snippet so that other people can make use of it.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the Math Class, but something like this should work for you

```
    string math = "5 + 3 * 3";
    string answer = new DataTable().Compute(math, null).ToString();
    answer = Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(answer)).ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    You can use the System.Math library. But System.Data library is related to ado.net operation. 
Example:
    string input=90
    var output =System.Math.Sin(Convert.ToDouble(input))); 
    output =System.Math.Cos(Convert.ToDouble(input)));
```